# Using RingtoneManager.getRingtone on LG optimus

Tags: android, ringtone, lg, optimus

I'm currently trying to play raw file as ringtone on LG optimus.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + curContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alert);
mDefaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(curContext, uri);
mDefaultRingtone.play();
```

I'm using this code on all other phones and it's fine.
on the LG devices(i have 2 Optimus devices - OS 2.2.2 and 2.3.3) it always plays the default 
system ringtone and not my resource.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**I FOUND AN OVERRIDE**

just for the mDefaultRingtone i use a media player item.

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, mUriForDefaultItem);
```

Then upon click i play the sound according to list position.